# How to check a radio button based on user input in a Django Template?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to check a specific radio button if one or two of the values of my two input fields exceeds a certain number. I am currently using Django Form to render both the text-boxes and the radio buttons:

Like this:

**The Radio Button:**

```
'gap_result': HorizontalRadioSelect(
            choices=NG_gap,
            attrs={
                'default': 'OK',
                'class': 'radio colorC',
                'style': ' margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 25px;',
                'name': 'radio_Gap',
                'id ': 'radio_Gap_Result',
            }),
```

**The two textboxes:**

```
        'gap_X': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control cent ',
                'placeholder': 'X',
                'type': 'text',
                'id': 'gap_X',
                # 'readonly': 'false',
            }),
        'gap_Y': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control cent ',
                'placeholder': 'Y',
                'type': 'text',
                'id': 'gap_Y',
            }),
```

What I need is to change the radio button to be **OK** if neither of the values exceeds 8 and then **NG** if it does.

Here's a visual representation:

[image]

Here's what I have in my template using the django forms:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class = "col-3">
    <div class="form-text">
      {{form.gap_X}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-3">
    <div class="form-text">
      {{form.gap_Y}}
    </div>
  </div>
    {{form.gap_result}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var gap_X = document.getElementById("gap_X");
    var gap_Y = document.getElementById("gap_Y");

    
    gap_X.addEventListener('keyup', calculate); 
    gap_Y.addEventListener('keyup', calculate); 
    
    function calculate() {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(gap_X.value))) gap_X.value = 0;
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(gap_Y.value))) gap_Y.value = 0;

        if (parseFloat(gap_X.value) + parseFloat(gap_Y.value) > 8) {
          document.getElementById("radio_Gap_Result_0").checked = true;
          document.getElementById("radio_Gap_Result_1").checked = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("radio_Gap_Result_0").checked = false;
          document.getElementById("radio_Gap_Result_1").checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to update with the IDs for each of your radio choices

Comment: How do you update the ID for each radio button if I declared it as one in forms.py?

Comment: Run it and view the source code in the browser. It will list them by IDs.